# Within Orbeon Forms, how can my forms created with Form Builder use PostgreSQL for persistence?

Tags: java, postgresql, orbeon

I am interested to buy commercial version of [Orbeon Forms](http://www.orbeon.com) and use with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) database, but Orbeon Forms is officially supporting only Oracle, MySQL and eXist databases. I can see from Orbeon Forms website that they have some kind of API to allow integration also to other databases than above.

So, how can I use Orbeon Forms with PostgreSQL database? I would appreciate step-by-step guide as I am not an experienced programmer.

Comment: That's a little broad. Can you tell us what you've already tried?

Comment: Actually I haven't yet tried anything. The problem is, I can't find any guide from the web how to use Orbeon with PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've editing the question to be more straight to the point, and also edited @Funtik's answer to mention how this can be implemented (not just point to Orbeon's support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, forms created with Form Builder can use Oracle, MySQL, and eXist for persistence, and as of me writing this answer, PostgreSQL is not supported out of the box.

However persistence is done trough a REST calls, so you can write services that conform to the [documented REST API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api), and persists data to PostgreSQL. You can also check the code of the [existing implementations for Oracle and MySQL](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence), on which you can base your own code. And if you'd rather Orbeon do it for you, they can do so under a [Dev Support plan](http://www.orbeon.com/services).

Comment: I have discussed with Orbeon Forms staff via email, but instead of providing guide to use Orbeon Forms with PostgreSQL, they suggested creating a "postgresql" directory in https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence, and adapting the Oracle or MySQL version of the code.

Comment: Hi,@Jusle, I'm unable to configure the Postgres DB for the Orbeon Forms. Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201679/orbeon-forms-postgres-db-connection . Have you find any solution?Can you please guide to me how to configure Orbeon forms in Postgres DB?.