# Orbeon Forms Postgres DB connection

Tags: postgresql, orbeon

I have tried to save the **Orbeon forms** in **Postgres DB**. I created **data bases persistence layer** but still forms are stored in the default **eXist DB**. I have created context(Data Base source) in the "Server.xml" from the tomcat7 and I have created "properties-local.xml" file in the Orbeon4.8 (orbeon/src/resources/config/properties-local.xml). My reference is  [this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Relational-Database-Setup#postgresql).

Some one help me how to save the orbeon forms in Postgres DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the database resource is configured, you can tell Orbeon to use it by adding a like like this to your properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="postgresql"/>
```

You can see the default configuration for the resource names Orbeon accepts out of the box in [properties-form-runner.xml](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/config/properties-form-runner.xml).

Exist will still be used for the example forms. But you can disable it with:

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active" value="false"/>
```

If you need to define a resource with a name other than the default names (e.g. postgresql), you will need to provide more information as shown below (remember to replace all occurances of pg_other_name with your resource name).

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="pg_other_name"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.uri" value="/fr/service/postgresql"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.datasource" value="pg_other_name"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.create-flat-view" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.autosave" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.permissions" value="true"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.pg_other_name.versioning" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "created context in the Server.xml".

In tomcat's `server.xml` you should have a datasource defined. For example:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource
        name="jdbc/postgresql"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="3"
        maxActive="10"
        maxIdle="20"
        maxWait="30000"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        validationQuery="select 1"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        poolPreparedStatements="true"
        username="orbeon"
        password="orbeon"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;socketTimeout=30&amp;tcpKeepAlive=true"/>

</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Then in tomcat's `context.xml` you should have a ResourceLink for the datasource:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgresql" name="jdbc/postgresql" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

`properties-local.xml` should be either in `webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config` or in an external directory you have defined in tomcat's `context.xml`, for example:

```
<Parameter name="oxf.resources.priority.0" override="false" value="org.orbeon.oxf.resources.FilesystemResourceManagerFactory"/>
<Parameter name="oxf.resources.priority.0.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory" override="false" value="C:/orbeon_resources"/>
```

In that case the `properties-local.xml` should be here: `C:\orbeon_resources\properties-local.xml`. See [Storing configurations outside of the Orbeon Forms war file](http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/03/storing-configurations-outside-of.html).

Also, make sure you have performed the [Orbeon Forms setup](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Relational-Database-Setup#orbeon-forms-setup). That is general database configuration, not specific to postgresql or any other database implementation. The examples they give are for `oracle` but you can just replace `oracle` with `postgresql`.

Comment: Sorry It is not working. I have a question orbeon forms 4.8  will support the  postgresql 9.2 ?.

Comment: I don't know about support for specific versions. I have only used Orbeon with Oracle 11g and 12c. If when you say "it's not working" you mean it's still saving to the eXist database then that would not be a problem with the version of postgresql. That would be a problem with your configuration. I suggest you edit your question to include specific details of your configuration. Right now you have very little info so it makes it hard to diagnose.