# How to make Orbeon 4.9 use PostgreSQL on Ubuntu?

Tags: orbeon

I would like Orbeon 4.9 to save Orbeon forms definitions in a PostgreSQL database, not in the default Exist database.

Although I think, that I changed the configuration files based on infos on Orbeons docs and on Stackoverflow, I can't get it to work.

- I use tomcat7. For Orbeon I have a `orbeon.xml` context, see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gubaer/ceb3b4193923d351435e). It declares the datasource and the path to the `properties-local.xml` to be used.
- The `properties-local.xml`, see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gubaer/c43c4cfd552dfca6f3f3), includes the properties to prefer PostgresSQL over Exist for saving form definitions and to deactivate Exist.

Nevertheless, Orbeon is still saving forms to Exist and the tomcat7 access log still includes entries, which indicate, that Orbeon invokes the REST API of the Exist DB:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:00:14 +0200] "POST /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr?collection=orbeon/builder/data/f9275a3ae314b06e1c401f86115621f2fcfe60d3&username=&groupname=&method=GET HTTP/1.1" 20
0 176
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:16:46 +0200] "POST /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/data/?page-size=10&page-number=1&query=&lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 2633
```

Any hint what is missing in the configuration? I'm aware of this closely related Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201679) but the answers don't provide a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a context file should work, but I'd recommend you just put that configuration in your `server.xml`; I've found this to be less error prone, and this is also what is [recommended in the documentation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Relational-Database-Setup#postgresql-1). Maybe this won't help, but trying won't hurt.

I suspect that your `properties-local.xml` isn't read. First, to keep things simple, try putting that file in the directory where you uncompressed `orbeon.war`, in `WEB-INF/resources/config`. If that works, then you can go for a more complex setup with your own resources outside of the war. Walk before you run ;)

In your context, I see that you're trying to setup `/home/me/software/orbeon/config` as a resource directory. Then, your `properties-local.xml` should be in `/home/me/software/orbeon/config/config`, but from the comment on the Gist for that file it seems to be just in `/home/me/software/orbeon/config`.

Comment: Thanks! The hint regarding the configured path for `properties-local.xml` was helpful. I fixed it and now it seems to work.

Comment: @gubaer, excellent, I'm glad it's working, and thank you for the quick update.