# Orbeon forms can't configure postgres connection

Tags: java, xml, database, postgresql, orbeon

I can't configure the PostgreSQLdatabase connection. It's all ok with eXist database but when I configure `META-INF/content.xml` to use PostgreSQL I always obtain "There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator."

I've tried with this information but never change  [Orbeon Forms Postgres DB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201679/orbeon-forms-postgres-db-connection/39421690#39421690).

Here my `webapps/orbeon/META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/mysql"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="3" 
        maxActive="10" 
        maxIdle="10" 
        maxWait="30000"
        poolPreparedStatements="true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        validationQuery="select 1"
        username="orbeonuser"
        password="orbeonpasswd"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/orbeon?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;socketTimeout=30&amp;tcpKeepAli$
</Context>
```

And the `resources/config/properties-local.xml`:

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active"          value="false"/>
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"        value="postgresql"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.resource.uri"          value="/fr/service/resource"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.uri"             value="/fr/service/exist"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri"       value="/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.uri"        value="/fr/service/postgresql"/>
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.datasource" value="postgresql"/>

</properties>
```

Somebody have any suggestion?

I am using Orbeon 2016.2 CE.

Comment: Two things: I assume that by `content.xml` you mean `context..xml`? Please check that. Also, you need a `<Resource>` child element within `<Context>`. Please check that you are following the right format.

Comment: I made a typo myself, of course I meant `context.xml` (only one `.`).

Comment: Hi @ebruchez but can't understand your comments. You say that I must use two dots at the context.xml name? The code below is my META-INF/context.xml now. Only that...

Thanks for your reply and sorry but I don't understand your suggestions...

Comment: @EnriqueAmestoy The content of your `context.xml` is incorrect: you have something *inside* the `<Context>`, while those should be attributes *on* the `<Context>` element. See an example in the [Orbeon Forms documentation related to Tomcat](http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/tomcat.html#custom-context).

Comment: @avernet Where? I do a "copy&paste" from Orbeon Forms documentation. Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there was an error with your copy/paste? What I see in your post (which I edited, but I don't think I changed that) is that the format of the `<Context>` is wrong. So you have to fix that first. Please double-check, as, again the format is not correct.

Comment: Excuseme @ebruchez, I forgot the "Resource" tag, I've edited. But don't run. But someting more: with the same configuration but for MySql it's running! I don't find what I'm doing wrong with PostGresql

Comment: Check the Tomcat logs and `orbeon.log`. There should be an error logged somewhere.

Comment: Nothing important or relevant. Now I've installed with MySQL (few errors in user creation and data_sets at Orbeon documentation but it's all running. 
Somebody have Orbeon running with PostgreSQL and can share all config files, for example? Thanks all for coments or sugests!!!