# Integrating Orbeon Forms 2016.2.1 with Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, orbeon

I'm unable to connect/integrate Orbeon Froms with MS SQL Server.

Does anyone have a step-by-step guide to configuring Orbeon Forms with SQL Server?

My current environment:

- Orbeon 2016.2.1
- Tomcat 8.5.6
- jdk 1.8.0_112
- The above applications are installed on a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I have MS SQL Server 2014 installed on a separate server running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

I have extracted the orbeon war file into D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\webapps\orbeon

Tomcat is running successfully. I can access the apache Tomcat/8.5.6 home page.

Orbeon is running successfully. I can access the orbeon (Forms builder) home page.
I am able to build a form (which does not integrate with SQL Server).

I'm attempting to use: sqljdbc42.jar
This has been copied into "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\lib" and also "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\webapps\orbeon\WEB-INF\lib"

I've updated "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf\server.xml" with the following:

```
<Resource
     name="jdbc/sqlserver"
     driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     initialSize="3"
     maxIdle="20"
     poolPreparedStatements="true"
     validationQuery="select 1"
     testOnBorrow="true"
     username="xxxxxxxx"
     password="xxxxxxxx"
     url="jdbc:sqlserver://<IP Address>:1433;database=OrbeonForms"/>
```

I've run the ddl to create the Orbeon Forms tables, etc in my database:
https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/form-runner/src/main/resources/apps/fr/persistence/relational/ddl/sqlserver-2016_2.sql

I've attempted to implement the following example, but cannot get it to work.
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html

The drop down box appears in the form, but does not list any of the content from the database.

Have I missed some configuration steps in the above setup?

Thanks

Comment: The `<--Resource` means that it is commented, which would explain the problem you are seeing, if this is indeed what you have in your `server.xml`. Could you double check that? If this doesn't help could you put your full `server.xml` somewhere, like in a Gist and include a link, so we can check if we can spot an error? Finally, you might also want to check if you have any errors in your `orbeon.log` that can put you on the path to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The comments are not in the server.xml file. I added the comment for the above post, as it seemed to help with formating. The server.xml code can be found at the following link.   https://gist.github.com/SM777/4105e567287af7e6e65f7ef57e50416f

Comment: Here is the orbeon log. I stopped the tomcat service, deleted the orbeon log. Restarted tomcat, opened orbeon forms, and published tested my 'test form' with the non-working drop-down list. Thanks,,, https://gist.github.com/SM777/e638e1c2c901786bc95c84e44886a735

Comment: Got it about the comment. (I've edited your question to remove the comment, to remove a possible confusion.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add in the context.xml the ResourceLink for the datasource:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/sqlserver" name="jdbc/sqlserver" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

In analogy to the [postgres example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201679/orbeon-forms-postgres-db-connection/31293003) which was working in my tests.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It has helped a bit, but not resolved my problem completely. Previously the 'drop down menu' was not displaying anything. The 'drop down menu' should be displaying six values from a SQL Server 'department' table. Since I have added the above 'resourceLink', the drop down menu is now displaying six blank rows. It appears the drop down menu is 'selecting' the 6 rows from the SQL Server table, but is not displaying the department names.

Comment: I've created a Database Service:  Service Name=Department;  Datasource=sqlserver;  SQL Query= SELECT ID, DEPT from DEPARTMENT

Comment: I've created an Action:  Action Name=ListDepartment;  Condition=Run always;  React to=Form load;  Service to Call=Department;  "Set Response Selection Control Items":  Destinations Selection control=Department (control-4);  Items=/response/row;  Label=DEPT;  value=ID

Comment: Maybe a case sensitivity problem?  In your database the fields are written in uppercase ID and DEPT? Try to write the field names in lowercase.

Comment: @SM7 Getting the right number of items, but seeing them empty seems to point to the SQL running correctly, in the Actions Editor, the items expression being correct (for a database service, it should always be `/response/row`), but the label (and maybe value) expressions being incorrect. What is your SQL, and what are those expressions?

Comment: Avernet, Thanks for the followup... The SQL in the 'Database Services' is:  SELECT ID, DEPT FROM DEPARTMENT   The expressions in the 'Actions Editor' in the 'Set Response Selection Control Items', Label = DEPT,  Value = ID